# Adding a method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

Currently, I have 3 classes: Weapon.java, Warrior.java, and Game.java. I am trying to access the strike method from the Weapon.java. I'm assuming that I have to call the class and then the strike method but not sure how to do that part.

```
public class Weapon {
    // Part 1 of ICE16

// 3 properties: String type, int power, and String strikeMessage 
private String type = ""; 
private int power; 
private String strikeMessage; 

// In class Weapon, create a constructor that assigns values to each of these internal private properties of the class in the order above. 
public Weapon (String type, int power, String strikeMessage) {
    this.type = type; 
    this.power = power; 
    this.strikeMessage = strikeMessage; 
}

// Method 1
public int getPower() {
    return power; 
}

// Method 2 
public void strike() {
    System.out.println("Weapon of type " + type + " has power " + power);
    System.out.println(strikeMessage);
}

// Method 3
public void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power; 
}
```

}

```
public class Warrior {
// Part 2 of ICE16

// 4 properties: int age, String name, int expLevel, Weapon weapon 
private int age = 0; 
private String name = ""; 
private int expLevel = 0; 
private Weapon weapon; 

// Create a constructor that assigns each value to the property 
public Warrior(int age, String name, int expLevel, Weapon weapon) {
    this.age = age; 
    this.name = name; 
    this.expLevel = expLevel; 
    this.weapon = weapon; 
}

// Method 1 
public void attack() {
    System.out.println("Warrior, " + name + " with experience level " + expLevel + "attacks!");
} 

// Call strike method from Weapon.java


// Method 2 
public void assignWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon; 
}
```

Comment: I wonder you want to strike with your weapon just during the attack, so, in attack() method, try to add this.weapon.strike()

Answer (score 0):

The `Warrior` class has a `Weapon` member which you could use to call the method:

```
weapon.strike();
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the most part. In your `attack()` method call weapon's `strike()`

```java
public void attack() {
    this.weapon.strike();
    System.out.println("Warrior, " + name + " with experience level " + expLevel + "attacks!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Weapon class by making it the base class, your child class then inherits all public members of the Weapon class

`public class Warrior Extends Weapon`

Before calling the strike method, Create an object of the Weapon class, passing the right arguments to the constructors

`Weapon j = new Weapon("gun", 25, "very deadly");`

then you can go ahead and call the strike method with the object reference variable

`j.strike();`

Comment: This is ok but, I think composition should be preferred way over inheritance here. This way weapon can be changed and attack method can be delegated to the assigned weapon.